# How do I render nice desktop notifications from Java?

Tags: notifications, java

I am writing this very basic J2SE application which alerts the user with some info every now and then. Currently I am using the SystemTray and TrayIcon classes to show notifications, but I am not really pleased with that. It does not allow me to tweak the notifications, nor gives them a good look.

So, does anyone know an easy to use library to generate nice notifications?

btw, I will be porting to Linux (Ubuntu) to, but will be using notify-OSD there, which is exactly what I need.

Comment: You might be able to subclass TrayIcon and override displayMessage()

Comment: @jpm That seems like a reasonable idea. I kind of hoped somebody already did that. I cant be the first person on earth who needs this right? If I go with this solution, any tips on where to start with the drawing of the notification as I have no experience with that. Any reference of that is welcome.

Comment: Actually, looking into it, there doesn't seem to be a good way to do that portably. At the moment, are you just using the default look&feel? If so, you might look into trying a different one. Check out the [official tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) on the subject and see if that might give you what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shameless plug: I've just released a project called [Twinkle](https://github.com/spreiter301/Twinkle) that is pretty much Growl for Java Swing.

Comment: It looks great in concept, the only problem to me is the price...!

Comment: Thanks for the input! What would be an appropriated price in your opinion?

Comment: Well it depends really who you're aiming it at. In the corporate world that would be tuppence and if big companies needed that kind of tight integration I'm sure they'd have no problem paying for it outright. I think I just jumped in and expected it to be a nice little GPL utility that's all (which considering I'm pretty much solely working on open source stuff at the moment is probably due to my mindset than anything else!)

Comment: I think my wording wasn't that good because 'project' really sounds like open source. I reconsidered the price from the perspective of a developer (rather than the perspective of my wife ;-) ) and it really was high. Thanks again for the input!

Comment: The demo looks perfect! Exactly what I am looking for. But I have the same problem as berry120. I am looking for something to use in a very small open source utility, so a closed source notification system would not really fit into the app.

Comment: @KingWilliam Thanks for the feedback. I put a lot of work into it to make it look perfect on all systems so I hesitate to release the source code. But now I'm looking into the possibility to release an open source binary version that is free. I just need to get the license stuff sorted out. Is there such a thing as GPL for binary code? For example: "You must release your code under an open source license in order to use Twinkle for your project."

Comment: I just released it under GPL v3. Have fun :-)

Comment: @spreiter301 I saw your comments a bit late. That is just awesome. Looking forward to take the time to use this in my app.

Answer (score 4):

I' not aware of a Java library abstracting all OS specific desktop notifications. But if you know, you are limited to Ubuntu (and perhaps a limited number of other OS), you can create a own `Interface` and implement it for the specific OS.

- Ubuntu: You can access `/usr/bin/notify-send` via `Runtime` like this: `usr/bin/notify-send -t 30000 "Text1" "Text2" -i /path/to/48x48.png`
- Mac OSX: [Java Growl API](http://growl.info/documentation/developer/java/)

For JAVA implementations you may look at [Jazz](http://www.jazz.net/) or [Mylyn](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Integrator_Reference#Commons_API) (see [Java Desktop Notifications](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI/Notifications)).

Comment: The Ubuntu one is not the issue, I can use the java-gnome project there. Windows is the problem (disregarding Mac for now). I think I will go with your suggestion of creating the interface, and implementing notify-osd for ubuntu and Mylyn/Jazz for Windows. I will update here if I have results.

Comment: can you please elaborate the part about `Runtime`? Is it the method through which CLI commands are called in java?

Comment: Yes, that's right. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use [JCommunique](https://github.com/spfrommer/JCommunique) for cross-platform Java desktop notifications. Here is a short demo adapted from the [examples](https://github.com/spfrommer/JCommunique/wiki/Examples) on the wiki:

```
// makes a factory with the built-in clean theme
// themes are customizeable
NotificationFactory factory = new NotificationFactory(ThemePackagePresets.cleanLight());
// factories build notifications using a theme, while managers handle how
// how they appear on the screen
// this manager just simple pops up the notification in the specified location
// other managers do sliding, queues, etc.
NotificationManager plain = new SimpleManager(Location.NORTHEAST);

// creates a text notification; you can also have progress bar Notifications,
// icon Notifications, Notifications that ask for user feedback, etc.
TextNotification notification = factory.buildTextNotification("This is a title",
                                                              "This is a subtitle");
notification.setCloseOnClick(true);
// the notification will disappear after 2 seconds, or after you click it 
plain.addNotification(notification, Time.seconds(2));
```

Brief confession: I also am the creator of this project. It's open source so I don't get any revenue from it.

Some other libraries to have a look at:

#### Twinkle

- This is already mentioned in another answer so I won't say too much about it. I tried the Java Webstart demo and it looked pretty nice. It allows for some more complicated background color options such as gradients that JCommunique doesn't have.
- About 3,500 lines.
- Has a bunch of fancy styling options such as round vs. rectangle close buttons, gradient vs. solid color, and light vs. dark notifications. However, has just one sequential manager.
- The wiki has links to javadocs and a getting started document.
- No external dependencies (I think?).

#### JCarrierPigeon

- Very lightweight. Looking at the jar, it has just six classes.
- Depends on the "Timing Framework" library.
- The website shows that it can do some sliding in effects, but I don't think it does fading or other types of animations.

#### JTelegraph

- Requires JCarrierPigeon and "Timing Framework" in the classpath to build
- Has dozens of nice-looking icons included with the project. I'm not sure how these are licensed, but they could be useful if you don't have your own.
- As far as I can tell, it doesn't include many more features than those provided in JCarrierPigeon. It mainly includes a bunch of built in icons and a different API.

I can't post links to these since I don't have enough reputation, but they are easy to find on the internet.
Now I will *try* to objectively evaluate my own library in comparison with the above. Please keep in mind that this list is a bit more extensive since I know more about my project than the others. Let me know if there is anything that I'm missing.

#### JCommunique

- Many features. As far as Notifications go, there are TextNotifications, IconNotifications, AcceptNotifications, and ProgressNotifications (show a progress bar). NotificationManagers handle how Notifications show. These include SimpleManager, QueueManager (scrolls down old Notifications to reveal new ones), SlideManager (slides Notifications into position), and SequenceManager (only shows a Notification when the previous one has disappeared).
- Relatively large. I think it clocks in at about 2,500 lines in total.
- Has a wiki with a number of examples.
- Notifications look a bit plain because they can only be one solid color. Twinkle wins in this respect; it has gradients and outlines around its notifications.
- A handful of built-in themes. At time of writing these include dark, light, and aqua. You can also add your own.
- No external dependencies other than Java.

Comment: I've undeleted this one since you put a lot of work into it. However, the question is off-topic by our standards, so it is now closed.